# PHP 5.3 on IIS gives 404 error in CGI mode

Tags: iis, php, cgi

Slowly losing my mind here. I had PHP 5.2 working fine
(ISAPI) under IIS, but for some extension I needed 5.3. So
no worries, I installed this but it turns out ISAPI is not
supplied anymore.

I followed the install tutorials for fastcgi and ended up
with a 500 internal server error for every PHP page served.

So my current situation is:
I have fastcgi removed.
In my websites I have added PHP (head, get, post) and routed
them to c:\php\php-cgi.exe.

Result: every PHP page I try (even the ones with just text)
gives 404 not found error. Any HTML file I put in the same
folder, serves without a hitch.

Who can help me please... How hard can something like this
be right? For me apparently very hard.

Extra information:

- ran the installer as suggested below. Set it to use fastcgi.
- my `fcgiext.ini` file looks like this now:
  [types]
  php=c:\php\php-cgi.exe
  [c:\php\php-cgi.exe]
  exepath=c:\php\php-cgi.exe
- from the command-line a 3 line PHP file with just `phpinfo();` works fine
- from the server the same PHP file with just `phpinfo();` results in the internal server 500 error.
- from the server a PHP file with just text works fine
- when changing the document types in IIS management console and point the PHP extension directly to `c:\php\php-cgi.exe` results in 404 for every PHP file
- the `php.ini` is the `php.ini.production` file which came in the distribution. No edits were made.

Setting the IIS PHP handler directly to PHP (not via
fastcgi) `c:\php\php-cgi.exe` results in the following:

- display a PHP page with only text....works fine
- display a page with only `phpinfo();` results in 404 not found

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. In the php.ini there are some values 
which need to be set for CGI and IIS. The force_redirect 
needs to be 0. Furthermore, the PHP extension needs to be 
added in the webextensions sections of IIS.

Those things fixed the problems.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the installer .msi?

For the rc4 of php 5.3 it's located at http://windows.php.net/downloads/qa/php-5.3.0RC4-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.msi.

But test it on another non-productive server first. Edit: it's a release candidate anyway, so you might want to try the installer on a test-test-server...

Comment: does this installer also configure iis?

Comment: you tell me ;-) It's quite a while since I tried the installer but back then, yes, it had a IIS/cgi installer routine. So, if you have a spare VM or an IIS server that doesn't matter (much) it's worth a shot if you're tired of trying the manual installation walktroughs. I'm not sure how well the installer copes with previous incomplete/flawed attempts to install php manually and therefore would really try this on another server first.

Comment: ah btw: the installer version I tried made some registry entries that affects the php runtime configuration. You might want to keep an eye on that. The key is HKLM\SOFTWARE\PHP\ as described at http://de.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.windows

Comment: hi, thanks for the help so far. I ran the installer but still no go. Changed a few other things, see my editted begin question for what I tried

Comment: -1 because installer results in all PHP files returning 404 error. 404 means FILE NOT FOUND. But the file exists. So this is an incredibly bad solution.